# Multiple headers in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, header, web

I'm to code a webpage where a large header is at the top of the page. This header contains the navigation bar, the logo and the website title. Once the user starts scrolling, I'd like this to switch to a small header with just a navigation bar, which stays at the top of the page as the user scrolls. I couldn't find any way to do this online, and thought this might be interesting for me and other people.

This is the large, first header, with css code:

```
    <style>
    header {
    background-color: #0097A7;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 2%;
    text-align: center;
    }

    h1 {
    font-size: 270%;
    margin: 2% 0;
    }

    nav {
    background-color: rgba( 255, 255, 255, .4);
    border-radius: 25px;
    width: 50%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    font-family: 'Neuton', serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    }

    nav a {
    color: #fff;
    display :inline-block;
    font-size: 100%;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 1% 4%;
    }

    nav a:hover {
    background-color: rgba( 255, 255, 255, .4);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-radius: 25px;
    }

    </style>

    <header>
      <h1><img alt="Logo" class="logo" height="50" src="media/logo.png">
      Fish & Chips </h1>
     <nav>
        <a href="index.php">Home</a>
        <a href="gallery.php">Gallery</a>
        <a href="about.php">About Us</a>
        <a href="contact.php">Contact Us</a>
      </nav>
    </header>
```

This is the header I would like to switch to:

```
    <header>
     <nav>
        <a href="index.php">Home</a>
        <a href="gallery.php">Gallery</a>
        <a href="about.php">About Us</a>
        <a href="contact.php">Contact Us</a>
      </nav>
    </header>
```

This is the code I found online to fix the header to the top of the screen

```
    <style>
    nav {
      position:fixed;
      top:0px;
    }
    </style>
```

I am unsure how to switch between these two headers. I assume it may be simple jquery like :

```
    if (xPos > 0){
    switch to small, fixed header
    } else{
    switch to large header
    }
```

Where xPos is how far down the page the user is.

However, I am unsure how to do this and can't find it online.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the reply! I've tried doing that, which explains how I can create a header which will stick to the top of the page. However, I still don't know how to switch between the two headers (the big one, and the small fixed one...) Thanks!!

Comment: Use some jQuery to change the class from relative to fixed when the position is located at the top of the page.

Comment: Can you at least provide us some code?

Comment: Alright, I've added some code I have and tried to explain better what I want to do. Hopefully this will help.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to implement something called a collapsing header. For starters: [YouTube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-6UuPT9x6Fc)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using Bootstrap responsive designs? check them out.